# java streams between java 8 and Java 7

Tags: java-8, java-7

I have the following method in Java 8  and I'm working in project using java 7:

```
public <T> List<T> getValues(CommandLineItem commandLineItemMod, Class<T> targetClass) {
    Object value = values.get(commandLineItemMod);
    ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (value instanceof Collection) {
        Collection<?> sourceCollection = (Collection<?>) value;
        result.ensureCapacity(sourceCollection.size());
        sourceCollection.stream().map(o -> convertValue(o, targetClass)).forEach(result::add);
    } else if (value != null) {
        result.add(convertValue(value, targetClass));
    }

    return result;
}
```

my question is how I can transfer the following line from java 8 to java 7 :

```
 sourceCollection.stream().map(o -> convertValue(o, targetClass)).forEach(result::add);
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
sourceCollection.stream().
                .map(o -> convertValue(o, targetClass))
                .forEach(result::add);
```

can be rewritten as:

```
for (Object o: sourceCollection) {
    result.add(convertValue(o, targetClass));
}
```

which (IMO) is a clearer way to write the code in the first place.

---

Having said that, public (free) support for Java 7 ended in 2015, and  premium (paid) support ended in Jul7 2019.  (See https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html).  So the application you are working on is on borrowed time.  I would have thought it would be more sensible to port the application to a newer Java version (or phase it out entirely) rather than expending valuable developer effort on backporting Java 8 code to it.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 doesn't support Stream API. You have to use a for loop:

```
 for(Object source : sourceCollection){
     result.add(convertValue(source, targetClass));
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the help